# What is the name of this statistical principal

Tags: probability, statistics

I was wondering how I could shorten this explanation into fewer words.  I am assuming their is a statistics term for this but I do not know it.  Is there one?

> If I flip a coin 10 times and get 8 heads I might not be surprised, however if I flip it 1,000 times and get 800 heads I should be surprised.

Comment: One could refer to the Law(s) of Large Numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@AndreNicholas gives two examples of principles that suggest your long run average for the  number of heads should stabilize.

For your specific case of flipping (I am assuming fair) coins, we also know that the mean and variance of this process are finite. In this case, we can further quantify your level of "surprise" using the Central Limit Theorem (CLT):

Let $H_n$ be the number of heads in $n$ tosses of a fair coin. Then the CLT states that:

$$2\sqrt{n}(H_n/n - 1/2) \xrightarrow{d} \mathcal{N}(0,1)$$

Therefore, for each $n$, we can quantify how "surprised" we should be at getting a certain number of heads using the normal distribution and the "standardized" number of heads (basically, mean number of heads minus expected fraction of heads then divided by standard deviation of the sample mean).

This relationship generally gets more accurate as $n\to \infty$.

So, you now have three principles to choose from. However, I've seen your particular statement/example mentioned in textbooks with regards to the laws of large numbers -- even though, technically, we the laws of large numbers do not provide warrant for being surprised by the results of any finite number of tosses.

Comment: It's so amazing that we can quantify "surprise" math is awesome!

Comment: @J.Doe others at this site may take issue with my conflation of  "surprise" with what I have described above (basically, you would calculate a two-sided $p$-value for your observed number of heads)...but probability is one way to quantify how unlikely a given result is given certain assumptions, with lower probability events generally associated with higher levels of "surprise". Take a look at information theory if you are really interested in this kind of stuff.

Comment: @J.Doe however, I agree with you: math is generally awesome...and I personally find probability and statistics really, really awesome :-)